# Job ID for Journey Builder Sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

> Is there a Job ID for Emails sent using journey builder.

```
Will be happy to furnish more details if required.
```

We had stopped a journey in between and modified it. 
Now we want to see who all subscribers was that particular email sent to using Job ID and perhaps exclude them from that particular journey or not to include them is subsequent journeys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Send Email Activity is a Triggered Send. Follow the steps below to view the Subscribers who have received the email:

1. Open the Email app
2. Select **Sends** from the Tracking menu
3. Expand **Journey Builder Sends** from the directory tree in the left pane
4. Open the corresponding Journey name and version directory
5. Click on the required email name to view and export tracking data

Comment: Is there a JOB ID for this send stored in any DE?
This would be needed in case we need to directly query the DE for email sends.
Pls advise.

Comment: It would not be stored in a Data Extension unless you have already created a Triggered Send Data Extension (create a new Data Extension using the Triggered Send template). Alternatively, you can query the [job data view](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_job/) to retrieve the job id.

Comment: Does that mean the Journey Builder Send has Job ID in Job Data View ?

In that case, what would be the use of Triggered Send DE.

Comment: Yes, the Job ID would be in the data view. The advantage of using a Triggered Send DE is that you can see all attributes used in the send and also add your own fields. A Job Data View requires you to write a query and target a DE to get this information.

Comment: Actually, I almost forgot. While Triggered Send DE's can be used with Triggered Sends, they can't be used with Journey Builder Triggered Sends, so you will need to use a query to select rows in the Job Data View.

Comment: This seems like a really bad process for identifying Job IDs